# Tensorflow: how to create tf.NodeDef() with Mul operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I want to create node with `Mul` operation and add it to existing graph.

Here is my attemp:

```
node1 = tf.NodeDef()
node1.name = 'MyMul1'
node1.op = 'Mul'
node1.input.extend(['conv1'])
node1.attr["T"].type = 1
```

The problem that I don't know how to specify constant on which input tensor in multiplied.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be applicable to your situation but I would strongly suggest using higher level APIs like [`tf.math.multiply`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/multiply). If you've lost the handle to the inputs in question you can use [`tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_tensor_by_name) and [`tf.Graph.get_operation_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name).

That said, what you can do to multiply with a constant is to create a `Const` op with a specified value and then use it's output as an input for this `Mul` op. [Example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py#L285) of op creation from r1.13 using [`tf.Graph.create_op`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#create_op). Although, a higher level API like [`tf.constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) might suit your needs better.